# 2004 conventional water heater in garage

Tags: water, water-heater

Our water heater has large rusted area (2"x3") located a inch or two up from bottom. How can we tell if we should change it? This is a 2004 conventional water heater

Comment: Is this a gas or an electric heater?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the rusted area?

Answer (score 1):

The rust you are seeing is to the outer casing.  There is a tank inside that.  Check to see if there is any moisture where the rust is, this would indicate a tank leak, which is non-repairable.  If it is dry, leave it be until it starts to leak.